# Node Js npm install error

Tags: node.js, npm

Im new to node js, im about to install a package via 'npm install', as you can see its 'ursa'.
So for now im stuck with this error C1083.

I use a 64bit maschine, OpenSSL is installed. Path of OpenSLL is
*C:\OpenSSL-Win64*

Error-Log
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQSct.png

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your C++ compiler has problems finding the OpenSSL header files.

The [Ursa GitHub page](https://github.com/Medium/ursa/issues/12) contains multiple issue topics about it not finding openSSL. There is a solution for ubuntu, but there is no general solution for Windows yet. I'd suggest asking for help there

Comment: Seems you got it to build. The warnings are usually fine, and if it works now, everything is okay.